# How to change Visual Studio editor drag and drop default action

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio Community 2022's editor is there any way to change the default action from

- select; drag & drop = move
- select; ctrl + drag & drop = copy

to

- select; drag & drop = copy
- select; ctrl + drag & drop = move

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using (note: the visual-studio tag explains that you should also mention the exact version of VS too.)

Comment: sorry, missed that.
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.1.5

Comment: so, no then I guess.